# Line shifts to the start when inserting {} into some JSX in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I keep running into this issue where entering a pair of opening and closing curly braces {} takes the entire JSX line and shifts it to the start (as illustrated in the picture).

Editor: VSCode

File Extension: .jsx (.js has the same behavior)

Extensions: I don't have any installed (only themes, etc)

[image]